# What is the standard limit on senses (vision, hearing)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, vision-and-light

Just as the title asks, what is the normal limit on how far a character can see/hear under normal conditions (normal lighting, no fog or other weather interference)?

Under the [Vision and Light](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/exploration-movement#TOC-Vision-and-Light) section all I can find are rules for decreased light, light sources and low-light/darkvision.

I've been told as a general rule to treat normal senses as double the limit of things like low-light/darkvision, so they would extend out to 120 ft. While this seems reasonable as a distance over which to see/hear something clearly, I'd like to know if there is a RAW mention of an actual range that I've simply overlooked.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate, my mistake. Turns out there is no RAW as of yet but the original question offers good suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a RAW answer on this, because it depends so much on what you're trying to spot. [I can see the moon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69407/can-you-see-the-moon-with-the-spot-skill) even though it's a *very* long way away in D&D terms. Even more so for the Sun; I'm sure you can make up similar examples for hearing as well.

Comment: I can do better than you - I can see the stars and they are *incredibly* further away than the moon. The Andromeda galaxy at 24,000,000,000,000,000,000 km is about the furthest thing visible to the naked eye.