# How far can a character see in shadowy illumination

Tags: dnd-3.5e, vision-and-light

There [is a similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31982/how-far-can-characters-see?rq=1), but it is about Pathfinder and not for shadowy illumination.

My question is how far can a character see (without low-light vision) in shadowy illumination? How many feet?

Comment: You might also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80209/8610) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65633/8610).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process follows the linked question, though the 3.5e rules are very slightly different.

Firstly, [shadowy illumination does not change how far someone can see](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#visionAndLight). It simply provides concealment inside sight range.

> In an area of shadowy illumination, a character can see dimly. Creatures within this area have concealment relative to that character. A creature in an area of shadowy illumination can make a Hide check to conceal itself.

A creature can see as far as their Spot skill allows. [Spotting something gets harder by -1 per 10 feet of distance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/spot.htm). One could reasonably assume it's DC0 to see something just standing there. We'll assume taking 10, but of course you can always roll to try to make it sweeter.

> Spot checks may be called for to determine the distance at which an encounter begins. A penalty applies on such checks, depending on the distance between the two individuals or groups.

And finally, [the maximum distance at which you can detect someone with Spot varies by terrain](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/wilderness.htm). It starts at 6d6×40 feet for plains.

Bringing these together, on the plains, in shadowy illumination, then if what you're trying to see isn't hiding you can see for whichever is least:

1. 6d6 x 40 feet
2. (10 + Spot) x 10 feet (at which point your Spot goes to zero from the penalties; naturally this is offset by size and other bonuses/penalties of the subject).

So to see a Medium sized (+0) menhir (DC 0) in a field at twilight, if you have a Spot of +8 (180') and the DM rolls a 23 on 6d6 (920') then you spot it at 180', assuming you're taking 10.  You'd see it at the same distance during the day.

To see a Medium sized orc assassin (Stealth +7) in that same field at twilight, as the shadowy illumination gives him concealment he can hide.   So instead of starting at DC 0 we're starting at DC 17 if he's taking 10. Your Spot of +8 means that, again assuming taking 10, you'll see him when he comes within 10 feet of you!

The terrain "max distance" roll is just a cap, which won't always come into play.  Other than that, the simplified version is to assume that

1. People see things at (10 + Spot) x 10' distance
2. People see sneaking things at (Spot - Stealth) x 10' distance.

Comment: Might want to get that pesky *Pathfinder* Stealth stuff out of this answer.

Comment: There is none as far as I know, you're going to have to be more specific.

Comment: RE: "To see a Medium sized orc assassin (Stealth +7)…" and "People see sneaking things at (Spot - Stealth) x 10' distance."